# ¿Cómo agregar una validación con set_rules en la libreria de form_validation de codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validación, codeigniter-3

en base a la problemática planteada, no se como validar la cantidad de números a ingresar en un input en codeigniter, mi intención es ingresar como máximo 9 dígitos, intenté realizar una validación en el controlador pero no se si estaré en lo correcto:

Controlador.php

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono','Telefono','required|max_length[9]');
```

Tengo mis dudas, por que con eso estaré declarando una cantidad máxima de caracteres pero no se incluirá los datos numéricos.

Lo otro que me gustaría saber es como puedo hacer que el 9 sea el número obligatorio a ingresar de manera inicial, antes de los 8 dígitos restantes.

Comment: @AlvaroJVanegas perdón era 9, no me había fijado que le había puesto 10

Comment: Puse mi comentario como una respuesta, ¿mi respuesta te pudo brindar alguna solución?

Comment: @AlvaroJVanegas Sí amigo! Muchas gracias, aunque todavía tengo mis dudas de como poder hacer obligatorio el ingreso de un número a modo inicial, por ejemplo que el número 9 se tenga que ingresar antes de los 8 números restantes.

Comment: Mm... no logro comprender con exactitud ¿te refieres a que necesitas que literalmente el número 9 esté antes de los 8 digitos restantes?

Comment: @AlvaroJVanegas Así es!

Comment: Acabo de añadir a mi respuesta una posible solución, prueba y comentame si realmente te funcionó, quedo atento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si colocas 10 estás permitiendo que tu input ingresen un límite máximo de 10 caracteres, por lo que entiendo en tu problema deberías colocarle `max_length[9]` ahora si lo que deseas que es obligatoriamente sea 9 digitos exactos puedes añadirle el `min_length[]` en teoría debe quedar así  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono','Telefono','required|min_length[9]|max_length[9]')` ahora puedes leer la [documentacion](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) y habrá ejemplos de lo que puedes hacer

Para lo que deseas de validar si el primer digito es el número 9 puedes intentar de esta manera

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono','Telefono', array(
      'required',
      'min_length[9]',
      'max_length[9]',
      function($value){
           $cadena = strval($value);
           if(strpos($cadena, '9', 0) === 0){
             return true;
           }else{
             return false;
           }
      }));
```

Comment: Amigo funcionó de maravilla! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Perfecto, puedes hacer las validaciones que tú quieras utilizando una función ánonima, eso sí debes retornar falso o verdadero para que la validación tenga efecto, saludos.